# Magento 2.4 cant delete old indices from elastic search AWS server

Tags: magento2.4, configuration, reindex, elasticsearch, aws

I am having a problem in elasticsearch it doesnt delete old indices when reindexing I am getting this message in var/log/exception.log

```
[2022-08-10 08:05:36] main.CRITICAL: {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"snapshot_in_progress_exception","reason":"Cannot delete indices that are being snapshotted: [[magento2_product_4_v12854/gZH6DirdQ2GBwVUVZoTP4w]]. Try again after snapshot finishes or cancel the currently running snapshot."}],"type":"snapshot_in_progress_exception","reason":"Cannot delete indices that are being snapshotted: [[magento2_product_4_v12854/gZH6DirdQ2GBwVUVZoTP4w]]. Try again after snapshot finishes or cancel the currently running snapshot."},"status":400} {"exception":"[object] (Elasticsearch\\Common\\Exceptions\\BadRequest400Exception(code: 400): {\"error\":{\"root_cause\":[{\"type\":\"snapshot_in_progress_exception\",\"reason\":\"Cannot delete indices that are being snapshotted: [[magento2_product_4_v12854/gZH6DirdQ2GBwVUVZoTP4w]]. Try again after snapshot finishes or cancel the currently running snapshot.\"}],\"type\":\"snapshot_in_progress_exception\",\"reason\":\"Cannot delete indices that are being snapshotted: [[magento2_product_4_v12854/gZH6DirdQ2GBwVUVZoTP4w]]. Try again after snapshot finishes or cancel the currently running snapshot.\"},\"status\":400} at /var/www/site/project/www/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Connections/Connection.php:675)"} []
```

I think that there is a misconfiguration in elastic search.

I am open to all suggestions, thanks in advance